# Send Commands form Visual basic to Google Assistant?

Tags: vb.net, google-assistant

I've looked just about anywhere to find an answer to my question.
Is it possible to send a command in Visual Basic to my Google Assistant?
For example: "Hey Google, turn on the lights in the living room"
I have done some coding in VB but I'm new on Stack Overflow, so I need some guidance..
Also: English is not my native language, so ignore te errors please. :p